# Count how many curl_multi requests have been made

Tags: php, rest, curl, parallel-processing, curl-multi

I want to know when each curl request has been made when using curl_multi.

My code so far:

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    if($running){
        curl_multi_select($mh);
    }
    $info = curl_multi_info_read($mh);
    if ($info !== false) {
        $i++;
        if ($i % 10 === 0 && $i>0)
            logTimeElapsed();
    }
} while ($running && $status == CURLM_OK);
```

I'm copying code mostly from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php).

My tests of hit has been strangly inconsistent. It seems to be working only sometimes. Perhaps when I make a small number of requests. So the issue might actually be to do with the end point. If that is the case, how do I keep track of whether the end point has refused my request?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://technosophos.com/2012/10/26/php-and-curlmultiexec.html . I usually use a library to handle it. For instance: https://github.com/MartinMajor/async-request

Comment: you don't remove completed handles from $mh , that probably has something to do with your inconsistency issue.```if ($info !== false) {curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$info['handle']);```

Comment: ick, also you may lose messages, if several handles complete in the same exec() then you only read the message from the first of them, and the rest of the handles' messages will be lost!  bad bug, ```while(false!==($info=curl_multi_info_read($mh))){curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$info['handle']);
$i++;
        if ($i % 10 === 0 && $i>0)
            logTimeElapsed();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My tests of hit has been strangly inconsistent

yeah, no wonder. there's a bug in your code if several handles finish in the same exec() call, you will only read the message from the first of them, and the messages from the rest of the handles will be lost! (edit: but it's not your fault, the bug comes from your copypasta at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php , someone should fix the docs!) (edit2: fixed the docs: https://github.com/php/doc-en/pull/102 ) lets say that before

```
    $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
```

$running is 2, and after it has finished, $running is 0, then

```
$info = curl_multi_info_read($mh);
if ($info !== false) {
    $i++;
    if ($i % 10 === 0 && $i>0)
        logTimeElapsed();
}
```

will only read the first message, and the message from the 2nd handle will be ignored forever! you need to read all the message, no matter if it's 1 message or 100 messages, to do that use while()

```
while(false!==($info=curl_multi_info_read($mh))){
```

then all messages will be read. also you should probably remove completed handles from $mh, so add

```
while(false!==($info=curl_multi_info_read($mh))){
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh,$info['handle']);
```

that way we ensure curl_multi_exec() won't try to re-run completed handles.. also there will be less job/cpu for multi_exec as it has a smaller list to iterate

also as a small optimization you should curl_multi_select() after reading the messages, not before reading them, then your cpu will be busy handling the messages while waiting for network activity, rather than sleeping until there is network activity, and THEN reading the messages from the previous exec(), put simply, the code should be faster if you just put select() after info_read(), not before.

Comment: Thanks for that! I can now reliably send the curl requests and keep track of when they succeed. Looks like I've got a separate bug related to only being able to send around 5 otherwise they all return 503 errors. Might be endpoint related, or php related. I'll create a separate question in a few found and link it here. Thanks for your help so far! :)